# Why aren't my pets getting paid? 

Tags: the-sims-2

I have The Sims 2 installed with all expansions and official patches (I miss stuff packs however).

I have a problem concerning pets: basically when they come back from work (after a few game days where everything works fine) they don't get a salary. They also can't get a promotion: it seems that the pets coming back home fails to trigger some routine.

I also tried totally erasing the Sims2 directory in my Documents and Settings folder (thus forcing the program to recreate the neighbors from scratch) but I still have the same problem.

However, this doesn't seem to be a common problem around the Internet. Is this bug known? Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm picture a dog going to work and demanding his salary with a series of barks.

Comment: I havent played sims in a long time, but am i getting this right?
you can now send your DOG to work? and it get promotions... and pay?

Comment: @Trew And still no diving board.

Comment: @Trew Yes you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a couple other people and have the same problem myself.  Seems to go away if Apartment Life is removed.  No other fix found yet.

Comment: I re-installed everything except Apartment Life and the problem disappeared. I guess that last pack is very buggy...